# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') at push.6044.ColorPickerComponent.ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I'm using colorpicker to choose a color but i'm not able to pick any color. I got the above mention error.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput [(value)]="color" [cpOutputFormat]="'hex'" autocomplete="off" [(colorPicker)]="color"
                  [cpPosition]="'bottom'" placeholder="BG Color" formControlName="color"/>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

And i also imported its modules

```
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';
```

Comment: can you share the ngOnInit?

Comment: i have share pls check and my "ngx-color-picker": "^6.8.0" version and i'm using angular 12

Comment: Move your initialization to `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: still i got the error that says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls') in this line of code get f() { return this.appointmentTypeForm.controls; }

Comment: solved the issue.Error is because of the color picker version

Answer (score 0):

Do you retrive the istance of `AppointmentTypeModal` with a `ViewChild` decorator or similar ?

Try to call the `initializeFormFields` method in the `ngAfterViewInit` instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: still i got the error that says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls') in this line of code get f() { return this.appointmentTypeForm.controls; }